# HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my website contacts us page  have a query form, when i submitted that form  its gets Error msg

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.  The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

So kindly help me i can't understand how these problem comming

Comment: Do you see the related posts on the right? This question has already been asked plenty of times

Comment: Probably the page you are submitting your form does not handle POST http method

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to my web.config to fix it:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```